# Finding Subgroup summary in a Group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summary

```
PPG Product Week        Sales
 P1  A      01/01/2018  50
 P1  B      01/01/2018  40
 P1  B      01/02/2018  30
 P1  A      01/02/2018  80
 P2  A      01/01/2018  100
 P2  B      01/02/2018  70
```

I am trying to find the summarize each PPG ,here and within each PPG I want to get the product with highest sale (overall) , something like below,

```
PPG   Max Product Sales
 P1      130 (This is sum of product A for ppg p1 across weeks)
 P2      100 (This is sum of product A for ppg p2 across weeks)
```

I have tried using the top_n(1,sum(sales)) in dplyr to achieve , but it failed, how can we go about this and can we extend it to find top n products by sales across weeks, to check for say if 80-20 rule, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Please do not share data like this. Always share output of `dput(head(data.frame))` to allow others to reproduce example at their end.

Comment: @TUSHAr got it , I did not know about that

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution using `dlpyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
```

First, group the data by PPG and Product, sum up the sales by group, then group by PPG only and take only the maximum value:

```
my_data %>% 
  group_by(PPG, Product) %>% 
  summarise("Max Product Sales" = sum(Sales)) %>% 
  group_by(PPG) %>% 
  summarise("Max Product Sales" = max(`Max Product Sales`))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    PPG `Max Product Sales`
  <chr>               <dbl>
1    P1                 130
2    P2                 100
```

with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)

my_data[, .(`Max Product Sales` = sum(Sales)), by = .(PPG, Product)][, .(`Max Product Sales` = max(`Max Product Sales`)), by = PPG]
```

which returns:

```
   PPG Max Product Sales
1:  P1               130
2:  P2               100
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any reproducible data, so let's read your text into a df.

```
df <- read.table(text=
                   "PPG Product Week        Sales
     P1  A      01/01/2018  50
     P1  B      01/01/2018  40
     P1  B      01/02/2018  30
     P1  A      01/02/2018  80
     P2  A      01/01/2018  100
     P2  B      01/02/2018  70",header=T)
```

We use `data.table` to get the sales within the groups of PPG x Product.

```
data.table::setDT(df)[,.(maxSales=sum(Sales)),by=c("PPG","Product")]
```

The result is then:

```
   PPG Product maxSales
1:  P1       A      130
2:  P1       B       70
3:  P2       A      100
4:  P2       B       70
```

Edit:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[,.(sumSales=sum(Sales)),by=c("PPG","Product")][,.(maxSales=max(sumSales)),by="PPG"]

   PPG maxSales
1:  P1      130
2:  P2      100
```